# Changing a video link dynamically to get the latest video

Tags: c#, html5-video, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery Template to show Video tiles on my Web site
.
The problem is that I would like to show always the latest video available from the Wall Street Web site. The videos are grouped according to dates.

For example for today's videos : `src="http://m.wsj.net/video/20120928/092812hubammarkets/092812hubammarkets_320k.mp4"`

I would like to dynamically change the `src` according to today's date.

Do you have an idea how to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a DateTime object for the current date and then put in the year, month, date in the string where they need to go (if the rest of the string is always constant).

Something like this:

```
DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now;
string year = testDate.Year.ToString();
string month = testDate.ToString("MM");
string date = testDate.Day.ToString();
string yearTwoDigit = testDate.ToString("yy");
string source = "src=\u0022http://m.wsj.net/video/"+year+month+date+"/"+month+yearTwoDigit+"hubammarkets/"+month+date+yearTwoDigit+"hubammarkets_320k.mp4\u0022";
```

\u0022 is the `"` character

That's a C# example, which is one of your tags.